# How can I assemble a file from iSCSI blocks?

Tags: disk, iscsi, san

I am new to iSCSI programming. I have security camera videos written in iSCSI blocks in a SAN. I need to construct playback of the some video from those blocks. I have hard time finding any tutorial or lead to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can get the iSCSI LUN attached to a general purpose computer of some sort, there are utilities that can aid in identifying video streams, such as "gspot".  I'd start by finding one and pointing it at the raw device.  See what it comes up with?  It's possible that the camera has some sort of filesystem on the LUN... but it seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with the [libiscsi tools](https://github.com/sahlberg/libiscsi). That should let you read the contents of the LUN from anywhere. Beyond that, there are no tutorials. Unless you've omitted details, you've basically lot a large block of data with video hidden in it somewhere.

Start by trying to figure out the structure of the contents of the LUN. If you're really lucky, it's just constantly rewriting a raw MPEG stream over the whole LUN, so you might copy some of the contents to a file and see what `ffmpeg` says about it. If you're unlikely, you've just got a bit file format reverse engineering problem on your hands, and that's far outside the scope of stack overflow, even if you gave us details. Some places to start looking:

- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Reverse_Engineering/File_Formats
- http://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/forensics/reverse-engineering-microsoft-exfat-file-system-33274
- https://hackaday.io/project/3149-reverse-engineering-design-file-formats